# Country Boundaries in Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

Google Maps standardly shows country borders when you type in a specific country (for instance "Switzerland"). [Link to Switzerland with borders](https://www.google.de/maps/place/Schweiz/@46.8131873,8.2242101,8z/)

I tried to understand the Code but it is really complex since

Is there any chance to get the same boundaries like in this example? I tried to locate the latitudes and longitudes data but I'm not sure if this is the right data:

```
[13, 10200002, 10200012, 10200029, 10200030, 10200040, 10200048, 10200053, 10200055, 10200066, 10200083, 10200103, 10200117, 10200120, 10200134, 10200149, 10200151, 10200153, 10200155, 10200157, 10200169], 86400, , , []];
    window.APP_INITIALIZATION_STATE = [
        [
            [1398041.137861972, 8.2242101000000005, 46.813187300000003], , [1024, 768], 13.1
        ],
        [
            [
                ["m", [7, 63, 42], 7, [256356426, 256356426, 256356157, 256355977, 256356989, 256356989, 256356989, 256356426, 256356426, 256356157, 256355977, 256356989, 256356989, 256356989, 256355065, 256355468, 256357045, 256357045, 256357045, 256356705, 256356705, 256356026, 256356059, 256357045, 256357045, 256357045, 256356705, 256356705, 256356026, 256356059, 256357045, 256357045, 256357045, 256356705, 256356705, 256356026, 256356059, 256356059, 256356187, 256356591, 256356591, 256356591]],
                ["m", [6, 31, 21], 4, [256000000, 256000000, 256000000, 256000000, 256000000, 256000000, 256000000, 256000000, 256000000, 256000000, 256000000, 256000000]],
                ["m", [8, 130, 87], 7, [256322553, 256353721, 256353721, 256353721, 256355974, 256355974, 256355974, 256329286, 256353721, 256354251, 256354251, 256355974, 256355974, 256355974, 256355468, 256357045, 256357045, 256357045, 256355478, 256355478, 256355478, 256355468, 256357045, 256357045, 256357045, 256355601, 256356532, 256356532, 256355468, 256357045, 256357045, 256357045, 256356494, 256356532, 256356532, 256353984, 256353984, 256353984, 256355601, 256356494, 256356532, 256356532]]
            ]
        ],
        [
            [
                [2, "spotlight", , [
                    ["gid", "9CYhwBOQY_7cJDe1gxwRVg"]
                ], , , , [, ["0x478c64ef6f596d61:0x5c56b5110fcb7b15", "Schweiz", , [, , 46.818187999999999, 8.227511999999999], 1, true]]]
            ],
            [
                [52, [
                    ["entity_class", "1"]
                ]]
            ]
        ],
        [, , , , , ")]}'\n[[\"0x478c64ef6f596d61:0x5c56b5110fcb7b15\",\"Schweiz\",[[1398041.137861972,8.2242101,46.8131873]\n,,[1024,768]\n,13.1]\n]\n,,,,,,,,,,,[[1,2,9,10,12]\n,,,\"maps_sv.tactile\"]\n,[[1,2,3,4,5,9,10,11,12]\n,[203,100]\n,,,\"maps_sv.tactile\"]\n,[,,,,,,81]\n]\n", ")]}'\n[[,[[,,,,,,,,\"lKw5U527D6Sr0QXY04HICQ\",\"0CAMQmBkoAA\",,,[\"0CAoQ1xooAQ\",\"/search?q\\u003dSchweiz\\u0026tbm\\u003dplcs\\u0026hl\\u003dde\\u0026authuser\\u003d0\"]\n,,[\"lKw5U527D6Sr0QXY04HICQ\",\"0CAQQ8BcoADAA\",,,,,,,,[,,46.818188,8.227511999999999]\n,\"0x478c64ef6f596d61:0x5c56b5110fcb7b15\",\"Schweiz\",,,,,,1,\"Schweiz\",,,,,,,,,,,,\"Europe/Zurich\",,,,,,,[[[\"1475517813748654502\",3,9,\"Schweiz\",\"Kapellbrücke\",1065.0436,[\"//g0.gstatic.com/landmark/image/1475517813748654502.140x75.jpg\",\"Fototouren\",,[124,75]\n]\n,,[[3.0,8.307240724041428,47.051594519651914]\n,[0.0,90.0,0.0]\n,,75.0]\n,\"lKw5U527D6Sr0QXY04HICQ\",\"0CAYQzCcoADAA\",,,,,[[[\"0x478ffb9f30ccc2e5:0x20b010d3c1d20e37\"]\n]\n]\n]\n,[\"14261343\",1,10,\"Schweiz\",\"Laufen-Uhwiesen\",930.2594,[\"//storage.googleapis.com/static.panoramio.com/photos/small/14261343.jpg\",\"Fotos\",,[123,75]\n]\n,[\"Francisco Criado Alonso\",,\"0CAgQyicoADAA\"]\n,[[3.0,8.61499802104269,47.677386967781246]\n,[0.0,90.0,0.0]\n,,75.0]\n,\"lKw5U527D6Sr0QXY04HICQ\",\"0CAcQzCcoATAA\",,,,,[[[\"0x479a821b5a4baf1f:0xffd5ff917d61b623\"]\n]\n]\n]\n,[\"zeo9lZXa1TOzjDhx2bcqUg\",0,1,\"Schweiz\",\"Spalen\",963.7776,[\"//geo0.ggpht.com/cbk?cb_client\\u003dmaps_sv.tactile\\u0026output\\u003dthumbnail\\u0026thumb\\u003d2\\u0026panoid\\u003dzeo9lZXa1TOzjDhx2bcqUg\\u0026w\\u003d123\\u0026h\\u003d75\\u0026yaw\\u003d120\\u0026pitch\\u003d0\\u0026ll\\u003d47.557898,7.581045\",\"Street View\",,[123,75]\n]\n,,[[3.0,7.58104539417463,47.557897918388015]\n,[120.0,90.0,0.0]\n,,75.0]\n,\"lKw5U527D6Sr0QXY04HICQ\",\"0CAkQzCcoAjAA\",,,,,[[[\"0x4791c92f5469510b:0x1a92b77c016cdeb7\"]\n]\n,[[\"0x4791b9b20c941101:0x219aaf37e33d176b\"]\n]\n]\n]\n]\n,,,\"lKw5U527D6Sr0QXY04HICQ\"]\n,,,,,\"https://www.google.de/maps/preview#!data\\u003d!4m16!2m15!1m14!1s0x478c64ef6f596d61:0x5c56b5110fcb7b15!2sSchweiz!3m8!1m3!1d2730.29510604096!2d8.227511999999999!3d46.818188!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!4m2!3d46.818188!4d8.227511999999999\",1]\n]\n]\n,,,,[\"1396288660378\",[[\"Europe/Zurich\",[\"MEZ\",\"Mitteleuropäische Zeit\",\"MESZ\",\"Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit\"]\n,60,[387817,60,392857,0,396553,60,401593,0,405289,60,410497,0,414025,60,419233,0,422761,60,427969,0,431665,60]\n]\n]\n]\n]\n,,,[[1398041.0967943876,8.22421005,46.8131873]\n,[0.0,0.0,0.0]\n,[1024,768]\n,13.1]\n,,\"lKw5U527D6Sr0QXY04HICQ\",,,[[[5]\n,[6]\n,[7]\n,[9]\n]\n]\n,[[[\"m\",[8,127,85]\n,13,[256356349,256356349,256356157,256355795,256355795,256355977,256356171,256356171,256356989,256356989,256356989,256357102,256357102,256356349,256356349,256356157,256355795,256355795,256355977,256356171,256356171,256356989,256356989,256356989,256357102,256357102,256332672,256353790,256355795,256355795,256355795,256353721,256356171,256356171,256356171,256356705,256356705,256356705,256356556,256332672,256355065,256355065,256355065,256353721,256354251,256354251,256355974,256355974,256356705,256356705,256356705,256356556,256329405,256355065,256355468,256355468,256357045,256357045,256357045,256355478,256355478,256356660,256356660,256356660,256356660,256329805,256355065,256355468,256355468,256357045,256357045,256357045,256355601,256356532,256356660,256356660,256356705,256356705,256356026,256356026,256355468,256355468,256357045,256357045,256357045,256356494,256356532,256356660,256356660,256356705,256356705,256356636,256356636,256356636,256356059,256356059,256355622,256355601,256356494,256356532,256356532,256356532,256356705,256356705,256356636,256356636,256356636,256356059,256356059,256355622,256354612,256356494,256356494,256356494,256356410,256354553,256324232,256356636,256356636,256356636,256356059,256356059,256355622,256354612,256356384,256356384,256356384,256355968,256354553,256309714]\n]\n,[\"m\",[7,63,42]\n,7,[256356426,256356426,256356157,256355977,256356989,256356989,256356989,256356426,256356426,256356157,256355977,256356989,256356989,256356989,256355065,256355468,256357045,256357045,256357045,256356705,256356705,256356026,256356059,256357045,256357045,256357045,256356705,256356705,256356026,256356059,256357045,256357045,256357045,256356705,256356705,256356026,256356059,256356059,256356187,256356591,256356591,256356591]\n]\n,[\"m\",[9,261,175]\n,13,[256319539,256319539,256330127,256354639,256354639,256354639,256347760,256347760,256347760,256330691,256326585,256328595,256328595,256319539,256319539,256330127,256354639,256354639,256354639,256347964,256347964,256355478,256355478,256355478,256354367,256354367,256311080,256311080,256330127,256330127,256330127,256354251,256354251,256356865,256356865,256356865,256355478,256354495,256354495,256286145,256329816,256329816,256329816,256353932,256355724,256355724,256356865,256356865,256356865,256355478,256354495,256354495,256257921,256329816,256329816,256329816,256353932,256355724,256355724,256356865,256356865,256356865,256354495,256354495,256354495,256329618,256349335,256356871,256357045,256357045,256357045,256355724,256355724,256354928,256354928,256354584,256354584,256329871,256356174,256356174,256356871,256357045,256357045,256357045,256356151,256356690,256356690,256356690,256356532,256356532,256356532,256356174,256356174,256356871,256357045,256357045,256357045,256356151,256356690,256356690,256356690,256356544,256356532,256356532,256356174,256356174,256356174,256353742,256353742,256353723,256356151,256356690,256356690,256357029,256357029,256357029,256356532,256353984,256353984,256353984,256353742,256353742,256330709,256355987,256355987,256356544,256357029,256357029,256357029,256356372]\n]\n]\n]\n,,,[[[\"1475517813748654502\",3,9,\"Schweiz\",\"Kapellbrücke\",1065.0436,[\"//g0.gstatic.com/landmark/image/1475517813748654502.203x100.jpg\",\"Kapellbrücke\"]\n,,[[3.0,8.307240724041428,47.051594519651914]\n,[0.0,90.0,0.0]\n,,75.0]\n,\"lKw5U527D6Sr0QXY04HICQ\",\"0CAwQzCcoAA\",,,,,[[[\"0x478ffb9f30ccc2e5:0x20b010d3c1d20e37\"]\n]\n]\n]\n,[\"12200897052196190411\",3,9,\"Schweiz\",\"Limmat\",1064.7417,[\"//g0.gstatic.com/landmark/image/12200897052196190411.203x100.jpg\",\"Limmat\"]\n,,[[3.0,8.541796561377344,47.372704998975095]\n,[0.0,90.0,0.0]\n,,75.0]\n,\"lKw5U527D6Sr0QXY04HICQ\",\"0CA0QzCcoAQ\",,,,,[[[\"0x47906b5e24df4d0f:0xeaf2a3d5b61dba0a\"]\n]\n]\n]\n,[\"16035295517055513176\",3,9,\"Schweiz\",\"Schloss Oberhofen\",1057.5472,[\"//g0.gstatic.com/landmark/image/16035295517055513176.203x100.jpg\",\"Schloss Oberhofen\"]\n,,[[3.0,7.668142085098925,46.72988216844148]\n,[0.0,90.0,0.0]\n,,75.0]\n,\"lKw5U527D6Sr0QXY04HICQ\",\"0CA4QzCcoAg\",,,,,[[[\"0x478fb20c5f273c43:0x921ba1376d36d82d\"]\n]\n]\n]\n,[\"12972660212690712003\",3,9,\"Schweiz\",\"Konstanz Town Hall\",1052.5317,[\"//g0.gstatic.com/landmark/image/12972660212690712003.203x100.jpg\",\"Konstanz Town Hall\"]\n,,[[3.0,8.859562684994534,47.659161161891866]\n,[0.0,90.0,0.0]\n,,75.0]\n,\"lKw5U527D6Sr0QXY04HICQ\",\"0CA8QzCcoAw\",,,,,[[[\"0x479af71d8b582135:0xb2574bc98ac41dcc\"]\n]\n]\n]\n,[\"10317932829748074867\",3,9,\"Schweiz\",\"Genf\",1048.0381,[\"//g0.gstatic.com/landmark/image/10317932829748074867.203x100.jpg\",\"Genf\"]\n,,[[3.0,6.14521622333327,46.205490978496094]\n,[0.0,90.0,0.0]\n,,75.0]\n,\"lKw5U527D6Sr0QXY04HICQ\",\"0CBAQzCcoBA\",,,,,[[[\"0x478c650693d0e2eb:0xa0b695357b0bbc39\"]\n]\n]\n]\n,[\"8605190079599930330\",3,9,\"Schweiz\",\"Castello Sasso Corbaro\",1041.7266,[\"//g0.gstatic.com/landmark/image/8605190079599930330.203x100.jpg\",\"Castello Sasso Corbaro\"]\n,,[[3.0,9.023224851597972,46.192658285984876]\n,[0.0,90.0,0.0]\n,,75.0]\n,\"lKw5U527D6Sr0QXY04HICQ\",\"0CBEQzCcoBQ\",,,,,[[[\"0x47844a25622a1d49:0xca18949203879a22\"]\n]\n]\n]\n,[\"14261343\",1,10,\"Schweiz\",\"Laufen-Uhwiesen\",930.2594,[\"//storage.googleapis.com/static.panoramio.com/photos/small/14261343.jpg\",\"Laufen-Uhwiesen\"]\n,[\"Francisco Criado Alonso\",,\"0CBMQyicoAA\"]\n,[[3.0,8.61499802104269,47.677386967781246]\n,[0.0,90.0,0.0]\n,,75.0]\n,\"lKw5U527D6Sr0QXY04HICQ\",\"0CBIQzCcoBg\",,,,,[[[\"0x479a821b5a4baf1f:0xffd5ff917d61b623\"]\n]\n]\n]\n,[\"55198385\",1,10,\"Schweiz\",\"Grosser Sankt Bernhard\",930.243,[\"//storage.googleapis.com/static.panoramio.com/photos/small/55198385.jpg\",\"Grosser Sankt Bernhard\"]\n,[\"arno18✿ܓ\",,\"0CBUQyicoAA\"]\n,[[3.0,7.1697810162816396,45.869004992131536]\n,[0.0,90.0,0.0]\n,,75.0]\n,\"lKw5U527D6Sr0QXY04HICQ\",\"0CBQQzCcoBw\",,,,,[[[\"0x478930086e5f4f85:0xc7f4103f0f6ab34b\"]\n]\n,[[\"0x478932827b84f139:0x7aecb20ea0206ac7\"]\n]\n]\n]\n,[\"6898947\",1,10,\"Schweiz\",\"Gordola\",922.21466,[\"//storage.googleapis.com/static.panoramio.com/photos/small/6898947.jpg\",\"Gordola\"]\n,[\"Heinz Brethauer\",,\"0CBcQyicoAA\"]\n,[[3.0,8.849198006010079,46.19656501148488]\n,[0.0,90.0,0.0]\n,,75.0]\n,\"lKw5U527D6Sr0QXY04HICQ\",\"0CBYQzCcoCA\",,,,,[[[\"0x4785b5e53a947451:0xb260ac35af579c48\"]\n]\n]\n]\n,[\"96531351\",1,10,\"Schweiz\",\"Totesee\",919.7149,[\"//storage.googleapis.com/static.panoramio.com/photos/small/96531351.jpg\",\"Totesee\"]\n,[\"David Guruli\",,\"0CBkQyicoAA\"]\n,[[3.0,8.338012036519872,46.56169999586]\n,[0.0,90.0,0.0]\n,,75.0]\n,\"lKw5U527D6Sr0QXY04HICQ\",\"0CBgQzCcoCQ\",,,,,[[[\"0x47857e532888bc99:0xd7eadcf5e0e8998d\"]\n]\n]\n]\n,[\"11205130\",1,10,\"Schweiz\",\"Bachalpsee\",919.40326,[\"//storage.googleapis.com/static.panoramio.com/photos/small/11205130.jpg\",\"Bachalpsee\"]\n,[\"Rafał Klisowski\",,\"0CBsQyicoAA\"]\n,[[3.0,8.024267010644309,46.667882015536435]\n,[0.0,90.0,0.0]\n,,75.0]\n,\"lKw5U527D6Sr0QXY04HICQ\",\"0CBoQzCcoCg\"]\n,[\"uk3RISu5fpUtobWCD6oEbA\",0,5,\"Schweiz\",\"Château-de-Chillon\",1005.855,[\"//geo0.ggpht.com/cbk?cb_client\\u003dmaps_sv.tactile\\u0026output\\u003dthumbnail\\u0026thumb\\u003d2\\u0026panoid\\u003duk3RISu5fpUtobWCD6oEbA\\u0026w\\u003d203\\u0026h\\u003d100\\u0026yaw\\u003d240\\u0026pitch\\u003d0\\u0026ll\\u003d46.414323,6.927944\",\"Château-de-Chillon\"]\n,,[[3.0,6.927943863763681,46.414322785880955]\n,[240.0,90.0,0.0]\n,,75.0]\n,\"lKw5U527D6Sr0QXY04HICQ\",\"0CBwQzCcoCw\",,,,,[[[\"0x478e9a5b4e7ae64d:0x9ac8ac6b196615be\"]\n]\n,[[\"0x478e9a5baedd65c3:0x22994259155c8307\"]\n]\n]\n]\n,[\"OPPHi5nsYpUAAAQIt9ldpA\",0,11,\"Schweiz\",\"Sankt Moritz\",990.8935,[\"//geo0.ggpht.com/cbk?cb_client\\u003dmaps_sv.tactile\\u0026output\\u003dthumbnail\\u0026thumb\\u003d2\\u0026panoid\\u003dOPPHi5nsYpUAAAQIt9ldpA\\u0026w\\u003d203\\u0026h\\u003d100\\u0026yaw\\u003d124\\u0026pitch\\u003d0\\u0026ll\\u003d46.490238,9.836884\",\"Sankt Moritz\"]\n,,[[3.0,9.836883533481567,46.490238075104074]\n,[124.41937,90.0,0.0]\n,,75.0]\n,\"lKw5U527D6Sr0QXY04HICQ\",\"0CB0QzCcoDA\",,,,,[[[\"0x478482076dc01a7b:0x279fdbbd3ec97825\"]\n]\n]\n]\n,[\"SKVqWzrpBN5UhRWls4r4uw\",0,5,\"Schweiz\",\"Lej Nair\",1002.10724,[\"//geo0.ggpht.com/cbk?cb_client\\u003dmaps_sv.tactile\\u0026output\\u003dthumbnail\\u0026thumb\\u003d2\\u0026panoid\\u003dSKVqWzrpBN5UhRWls4r4uw\\u0026w\\u003d203\\u0026h\\u003d100\\u0026yaw\\u003d207\\u0026pitch\\u003d0\\u0026ll\\u003d46.414453,10.016293\",\"Lej Nair\"]\n,,[[3.0,10.016292519379387,46.41445250295737]\n,[207.73595,90.0,0.0]\n,,75.0]\n,\"lKw5U527D6Sr0QXY04HICQ\",\"0CB4QzCcoDQ\",,,,,[[[\"0x478377a2cc6da2a7:0x18544ac6ab280a\"]\n]\n]\n]\n,[\"8V60OF03C-QAAAAGOsNMbw\",0,11,\"Schweiz\",\"Monte Brè\",990.5169,[\"//geo0.ggpht.com/cbk?cb_client\\u003dmaps_sv.tactile\\u0026output\\u003dthumbnail\\u0026thumb\\u003d2\\u0026panoid\\u003d8V60OF03C-QAAAAGOsNMbw\\u0026w\\u003d203\\u0026h\\u003d100\\u0026yaw\\u003d114\\u0026pitch\\u003d0\\u0026ll\\u003d46.003412,8.954945\",\"Monte Brè\"]\n,,[[3.0,8.954945036189512,46.003411920431205]\n,[114.02723,90.0,0.0]\n,,75.0]\n,\"lKw5U527D6Sr0QXY04HICQ\",\"0CB8QzCcoDg\",,,,,[[[\"0x478431ffb8e882ad:0x7dfc8ed852d365a1\"]\n]\n]\n]\n,[\"zeo9lZXa1TOzjDhx2bcqUg\",0,1,\"Schweiz\",\"Spalen\",963.7776,[\"//geo0.ggpht.com/cbk?cb_client\\u003dmaps_sv.tactile\\u0026output\\u003dthumbnail\\u0026thumb\\u003d2\\u0026panoid\\u003dzeo9lZXa1TOzjDhx2bcqUg\\u0026w\\u003d203\\u0026h\\u003d100\\u0026yaw\\u003d120\\u0026pitch\\u003d0\\u0026ll\\u003d47.557898,7.581045\",\"Spalen\"]\n,,[[3.0,7.58104539417463,47.557897918388015]\n,[120.0,90.0,0.0]\n,,75.0]\n,\"lKw5U527D6Sr0QXY04HICQ\",\"0CCAQzCcoDw\",,,,,[[[\"0x4791c92f5469510b:0x1a92b77c016cdeb7\"]\n]\n,[[\"0x4791b9b20c941101:0x219aaf37e33d176b\"]\n]\n]\n]\n,[\"PZnVeBUHOC3FGdc3ZQzmJw\",0,5,\"Schweiz\",\"Oberaarsee\",993.2363,[\"//geo0.ggpht.com/cbk?cb_client\\u003dmaps_sv.tactile\\u0026output\\u003dthumbnail\\u0026thumb\\u003d2\\u0026panoid\\u003dPZnVeBUHOC3FGdc3ZQzmJw\\u0026w\\u003d203\\u0026h\\u003d100\\u0026yaw\\u003d240\\u0026pitch\\u003d0\\u0026ll\\u003d46.547720,8.272986\",\"Oberaarsee\"]\n,,[[3.0,8.272986053391238,46.54772020463626]\n,[240.0,90.0,0.0]\n,,75.0]\n,\"lKw5U527D6Sr0QXY04HICQ\",\"0CCEQzCcoEA\",,,,,[[[\"0x478f80369032fcc5:0xd410feb5998ba44f\"]\n]\n]\n]\n,[\"MfR-ctTW5B0AAAQJOByLqg\",0,11,\"Schweiz\",\"Pilatus\",988.01294,[\"//geo0.ggpht.com/cbk?cb_client\\u003dmaps_sv.tactile\\u0026output\\u003dthumbnail\\u0026thumb\\u003d2\\u0026panoid\\u003dMfR-ctTW5B0AAAQJOByLqg\\u0026w\\u003d203\\u0026h\\u003d100\\u0026yaw\\u003d326\\u0026pitch\\u003d0\\u0026ll\\u003d46.979090,8.256221\",\"Pilatus\"]\n,,[[3.0,8.256220867874674,46.97908997148394]\n,[326.3383,90.0,0.0]\n,,75.0]\n,\"lKw5U527D6Sr0QXY04HICQ\",\"0CCIQzCcoEQ\",,,,,[[[\"0x478ff014bae60859:0xaa0bb4d8602e0bbc\"]\n]\n]\n]\n]\n,,,\"lKw5U527D6Sr0QXY04HICQ\"]\n,[[[2,\"spotlight\",,[[\"gid\",\"9CYhwBOQY_7cJDe1gxwRVg\"]\n]\n,,,,[,[\"0x478c64ef6f596d61:0x5c56b5110fcb7b15\",\"Schweiz\",,[,,46.818188,8.227511999999999]\n,1,1]\n]\n]\n]\n,[[52,[[\"entity_class\",\"1\"]\n]\n]\n]\n]\n]\n"], , [, , [, [2, 8.2242101000000005, 46.813187300000003, , , 8]],
            [, , ["0x478c64ef6f596d61:0x5c56b5110fcb7b15", "Schweiz"]]
        ],
        [9, 2, 8, 4, 5, 7, 3]
    ];
    window.APP_FLAGS = [, , , , , , , true, , , , 11, 11, 1, , , true, , true, , true, , , , , true, true, true, , , , , , true, , true, , , , , , , , true, true, , , false, , true, true, true, true, true, true, , , , , true, , true, , true, 2, 1, , , , , , , , , , , true, , , , , , , , , , , true, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , true, , , , true, , , , , , true, , , , , , , , true, , , , , true, , , , , true, true, true, true, , , true, , , , , true, , true, 24, , true, true, , , true, true, , true, , , 0.29999999999999999, , true, , 550, 250, , true, , , true];
    window.VECTORTOWN_FLAGS =
```

Answer (score 0):

You can download many country shapefiles free of charge from some websites. You can search in searchengine for shapefile.